# How to retrieve one servlet session attributes in another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have two servlets in my project 2nd being called from the 1st servlet. Im creating http session in first servlet and setting some attributes to that session object. How do i get the values of these attributes in second servlet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me out.Im struck with this for 2 days...

Comment: What code exactly have you so far? What exactly have you tried? How exactly did it fail? Have you for example tried replacing "setAttribute()" method call by a "getAttribute()" method call on the session object? I'm asking this because this is too obvious that wasting 2 days should surely indicate a more complex problem. So, please elaborate your problem in detail.

Comment: How are you calling the second servlet from the first? Are you forwarding the request or redirecting?

Comment: I got the solution.JB Nizet answered me.

Answer (score 4):

```
Object value = request.getSession().getAttribute("nameOfTheAttributeUsedInTheFirstServlet");
```

If two servlets are in the same webapp, they share the same session context, and the session is the same for both servlets. Of course, remember that a session is tight to a particular user.